# How do Virtual Hosts and TLS work together?

Tags: ssl, https, virtualhost

As I understand it Virtual Hosts work in HTTP servers by receiving a HTTP request from the client and examining the `Host` header, which contains `service1.example.com` or `service2.example.com`, etc. and then forwarding the request based on some rules in the HTTP server configuration.

But as I understand it TLS works as follows:

1. Client opens connection to server.
2. Client and server have a handshake where the client checks the server's certificate is valid *for the name the client is trying to access*.
3. Client transmits the request.
4. Server transmits the response.

These two seem like they would be incompatible, the server doesn't know which TLS certificate to present to the client until after the request has been sent, but the client won't send the request until the handshake is completed.

They clearly aren't incompatible, I have run web servers with multiple separate TLS virtual hosts each with completely separate certificates. Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: Search for "Server Name Indication" here or security.SX or serverfault.SX. Also note _one_ certificate can support multiple hostnames using wildcard(s) since about 2000 and/or SubjectAlternativeName aka SAN or multidomain or UCC since about 2005.

Comment: I had a dim recollection of multi-hostname certificates but have only ever done this setup with separate certificates. Regardless SNI seems to be the answer, thank you.